# R - splitting column by legend from the other one

Tags: r

I've got data.frame like below

```
ID  age legend                 location     
1   83  country;province;city  X;A;J
2   15  country;city           X;K
3   2   country;province;city  Y;B;I
4   12  country;city           X;L
5   2   country;city           Y;J
6   2   country;province;city  Y;A;M
7   18  country;province;city  X;B;J
8   85  country;province;city  X;A;I
```

To describe it: there is third column (legend) with description of the value of fourth column (location). Order of the records in the rows of legend column indicate the order of value in location column.

As a result, I need to obtain the data.frame as below

```
ID age country province city
1  83      X        A    J
2  15      X     <NA>    K
3  2       Y        B    I
4  12      X     <NA>    L
5  2       Y     <NA>    J
6  2       Y        A    M
7  18      X        B    J
8  85      X        A    I
```

To describe, I need to extract info from legend column and set them  as name of new columns and then fill with appropriate information from location column. I cannot just split the columns by ; because there is different number of records in each rows. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `separate_rows` and then `spread` the data out from long to wide.  If the order of columns does not matter then the `select` line can be omitted.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
  separate_rows(legend, location) %>% 
  spread(legend, location) %>%
  select(ID, age, country, province, city) # optional
```

giving:

```
  ID age country province city
1  1  83       X        A    J
2  2  15       X     <NA>    K
3  3   2       Y        B    I
4  4  12       X     <NA>    L
5  5   2       Y     <NA>    J
6  6   2       Y        A    M
7  7  18       X        B    J
8  8  85       X        A    I
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
ID  age legend                 location     
1   83  country;province;city  X;A;J
2   15  country;city           X;K
3   2   country;province;city  Y;B;I
4   12  country;city           X;L
5   2   country;city           Y;J
6   2   country;province;city  Y;A;M
7   18  country;province;city  X;B;J
8   85  country;province;city  X;A;I"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```